# Post multiple string values from jquery ajax to C# controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I post multiple strings form jquery ajax to a C# controller action? I have this working with one string but not sure how to post more than one string to a method in c# taking two string parameters.

Jquery code:

```html
  var data = {
                date: "s",
                index: "sa"
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/PersistTimeOfDay",

                type: 'post',


                data: JSON.stringify(data),

                contentType: 'application/json',


                success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);

                },

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(jqXHR.status);
                }
            })
```

C# code:

```html
        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PersistTimeOfDay([FromBody] string date, [FromBody] string index)
        {
            return Json("s");

        }
```

Would love to finally achieve this! I have tried a number of combinations and either get one or all values null.

Comment: Using web console and checking Network tab, what does the payload and response look like?

Comment: @Gurdip sira ..have you  checked my answer ,i think it will fulfill your requirement

Comment: In doc about [[FromBody] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-attribute), you can find "*`Don't apply [FromBody] to more than one parameter per action method.`*" And as other community members shared, you can pass data via a custom model to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

By doing like this,

you can pass multiple parameters as many you want

Just pass data as model from your js like

```
    var employee = new Object();  
    employee.Name = "ABC" 
    employee.Address = "PUNE";  
    employee.Location = "PUNE";  

    $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/Home/PersistTimeOfDay",  
            data: JSON.stringify(employee),  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function(response) {  
               // Do your code here
            },  
            failure: function(response) {  
                alert(response.responseText);  
            },  
            error: function(response) {  
                alert(response.responseText);  
            }  
        });
```

and create one model as Employee like

```
public class Employee 
{  
    public string Name {get;set;}  
    public string Designation {get;set;}  
    public string Location {get;set;}  
}
```

and just add code in your controller

```
  [HttpPost]  
  public JsonResult PersistTimeOfDay(Employee employeeData) {  
        Employee employee = new Employee {  
            Name = employeeData.Name,  
                Designation = employeeData.Designation,  
                Location = employeeData.Location  
        };  
        return Json(employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Is your url correct?

```
   $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/PersistTimeOfDay",
                    type: 'post',
                     data: JSON.stringify( { "date":"s" , "date":"sa" }),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert(jqXHR.status);
                    }
                })
```

But i use this method to pass whole form data

```
 data:$('form#yourformuniqueid').serialize(),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to achieve it

**C#**

```
public class ParamModel 
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string index { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PersistTimeOfDay([FromBody] ParamModel model)
{
  return Json("s");
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/PersistTimeOfDay",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ date: "s" , date:"sa" }),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(jqXHR.status);
        }
});
```

Comment: Hmm controller gets hit but values are null.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look @Gurdip sira